# Transpose row data to column data

Tags: row, grouping, transpose

Working on report where I need to see the attending physician and the primary care physician in a single row.  Currently I have the data in 2 rows.  I need 1 column the attending and the 2nd column the primary.
Current:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDs64.png)

What I need:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mA9tf.png)

Thanks in advance!

thought I could use a crosstab but I don't have numeric data.
Sorry, trying to learn crystal

Comment: Please add your tables as text, not as images.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which database or ORM (if applicable) you're using, but if you know the output format you'd like, you can write a SQL query to get the data you like. I'd start by selecting the fields you want into your query (I'm using a CASE statement):

```
SELECT
 ROOM,
 PATIENT_NAME,
 NUMBER,
 CASE 
   WHEN PHYS_RELATION_TYPE = 'ATTENDING'
    THEN PHYSICIAN
  END AS ATTENDING,
  CASE 
    WHEN PHYS_RELATION_TYPE = 'PRIMCARE'
      THEN PHYSICIAN
    END AS PRIMCARE,
  SERVICE
FROM patient_data
```

That should give you an output like this:

```
 room | patient_name  |  number  | attending | primcare  | service  
------+---------------+----------+-----------+-----------+----------
 402  | Hello Kitty   | 10543826 | Dr Suess  |           | INT CARE
 402  | Hello Kitty   | 10543826 |           | Dr Pepper | INT CARE
 403  | Charlie Brown | 10544027 | Dr Phil   |           | OBSERVAT
 403  | Charlie Brown | 10544027 |           | Dr Grey   | OBSERVAT
 404  | Scooby Doo    | 10544481 |           | Dr Pepper | MEDICAL
 404  | Scooby Doo    | 10544481 | Dr Suess  |           | MEDICAL
```

Now you can group your data to get the condensed results you're looking for:

```
SELECT
  ROOM,
  PATIENT_NAME,
  NUMBER,
  STRING_AGG(
  CASE 
    WHEN PHYS_RELATION_TYPE = 'ATTENDING'
    THEN PHYSICIAN
  END, ', '
  ) AS ATTENDING,
  STRING_AGG(
  CASE 
    WHEN PHYS_RELATION_TYPE = 'PRIMCARE'
    THEN PHYSICIAN
  END, ', '
  ) AS PRIMARY,
  SERVICE
FROM patient_data
GROUP BY ROOM, PATIENT_NAME, NUMBER, SERVICE;
```

That should give you a result something like this:

```
 room | patient_name  |  number  | attending |  primary  | service  
------+---------------+----------+-----------+-----------+----------
 402  | Hello Kitty   | 10543826 | Dr Suess  | Dr Pepper | INT CARE
 403  | Charlie Brown | 10544027 | Dr Phil   | Dr Grey   | OBSERVAT
 404  | Scooby Doo    | 10544481 | Dr Suess  | Dr Pepper | MEDICAL
```

Note that I'm using the [PostgreSQL "STRING_AGG" function](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-aggregate-functions/postgresql-string_agg-function/), which takes a column and a delimiter (I used a comma) - if you had more than one primary care doctor for a single patient (for example), their names would be displayed as "Dr Suess, Dr Pepper". Depending on how you use this data, this reuslt might not be what you want! Good luck